# como evitar que el programa finalice

Tags: java, array, netbeans

Hola estoy realizando un menu de usuario, en el cual se puede agregar jugadores, mostrar de a un

jugador, editar un jugador, y mostrar todos los jugadores, pero no se como puedo hacer para que al

entrar en el case 3 "que es para modificar" el programa no se

detenga, si no que vuelva a mostrarme el "menu" con las 5 opciones, y a si poder verificar si se

modifico el jugador con el case 2 que es para buscar al jugador por el id.

tuve que reducir el codigo por que no se me deja poner todo el codigo.

```
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int contador = 0;
    int opcion;
    
    Jugador [] jugadores = new Jugador[5];
    
    do{      
        System.out.println("1. Agregar un Jugador");
        System.out.println("2. Mostar un Jugador");
        System.out.println("3. Editar un Jugador");
        System.out.println("4. Mostrar toda la convocatoria");
        System.out.println("5. Salir");
        
        System.out.println("Digite una opcion");
        
        opcion = entrada.nextInt();
        
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                
                jugadores[contador]= new Jugador();
                
                System.out.println("Digite el id del jugador:");
                jugadores[contador].setId(entrada.nextInt());
                
                System.out.println("Digite el nombre:");
                jugadores[contador].setNombre(entrada.next());
                
                System.out.println("Digite el apellido:");
                jugadores[contador].setApellido(entrada.next());
   
                contador ++;
                
                break;
                
            case 2:
                
                System.out.println("Digite el id del jugador");
                int id = entrada.nextInt();
                for (int i=0; i<jugadores.length;i++){
                    if (id == jugadores[i].getId()) {
                    System.out.println(jugadores[i].getNombre());
                    System.out.println(jugadores[i].getApellido());
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("El id no esta registrado");
                    }
                }
                break;
                
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Digite el id del jugador a modificar");
                int idSearch = entrada.nextInt();
                for (int i=0; i<jugadores.length;i++) {
                  if (jugadores[i].id == idSearch) {
                      
                    System.out.println("digite el nombre");
                    jugadores[i].nombre = entrada.next();
                    
                    System.out.println("digite el apellido");
                    jugadores[i].apellido = entrada.next();
                       }else{
                      System.out.println("El id no esta registrado");
                  }
                  
                }  
                break;                    
        }                           
    }while(opcion != 4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola estaba viendo la estructura de tu problema y te muestro en mi opinion otra opcion para poder realizar esta practica manteniendo los estandares que sugiere el problema. A continucacion muestro la clase Jugador, respetando los principios de encapsulamiento.

```
public class Jugador {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;

public Jugador(int id, String nombre, String apellido) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Jugador [id=" + id + ", " + (nombre != null ? "nombre=" + nombre + ", " : "")
            + (apellido != null ? "apellido=" + apellido : "") + "]";
}
```

}

Ahora te muestro la clase principal la que contiene al metodo main, esta clase cuenta con metodos correspondientemente en base a lo que solicita el ejercicio, manejando ciertos errores basicos en el ingreso de datos, los datos del jugador son registrados de manera dinamica dentro de una lista de juagadores.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static ArrayList<Jugador> jugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int opcion = 0;
    do {
        opcion = menu();
        realizarOperacionesDelMenu(opcion);
        System.out.println();
    } while (opcion != 5);
    System.out.println("\nPrograma Finalizado");
}

public static int menu() {
    int opcion = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("*********MENU*********");
        System.out.println("1. Agregar un Jugador");
        System.out.println("2. Mostar un Jugador");
        System.out.println("3. Editar un Jugador");
        System.out.println("4. Mostrar toda la convocatoria");
        System.out.println("5. Salir");
        System.out.print("Elija una opcion del menu: ");
        try {
            opcion = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(
                    "Error!, debes ingresar un valor numerico entero perteneciente a las opciones del menu.");
        }
    } while (opcion < 1 || opcion > 5);
    return opcion;
}

public static void realizarOperacionesDelMenu(int opcion) {

    switch (opcion) {
    case 1:
        agregarJugador();
        break;

    case 2:
        buscarUnJugador();

        break;
    case 3:
        modificarJuagdor();
        break;
    case 4:
        mostrarTodaLaConvocatoria();
        break;
    }
}

public static void agregarJugador() {
    boolean encontrado = false;
    System.out.println("\n\tREGISTRO DE JUAGADORES");
    Jugador obJugador = registroDatosJugador();
    for (int i = 0; i < jugadores.size(); i++) {
        if (jugadores.get(i).getId() == obJugador.getId()) {
            encontrado = true;
            System.out.println("\n\tYa existe un jugador registrado con este ID.");

        }
    }
    if (!encontrado) {
        jugadores.add(obJugador);
        System.out.println("**********Jugador registrado con exito.***********");
    }

}

private static Jugador registroDatosJugador() {
    int id;
    String nombre, apellido;
    id = agregarIdAlJugador();
    nombre = agregarNombreAlJugador();
    apellido = agregarApellidoAlJugador();
    Jugador obJugador = new Jugador(id, nombre, apellido);
    return obJugador;
}

public static int agregarIdAlJugador() {
    int id = 0;
    System.out.print("Ingrese el id del jugador: ");
    do {
        try {
            id = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Recuerda el Id del jugador debe ser un valor numerico entero y positivo.");
        }
    } while (id <= 0);
    return id;
}

public static String agregarNombreAlJugador() {
    String nombre;
    do {
        System.out.print("Ingrese el nombre del jugador: ");
        nombre = scan.nextLine();
    } while (nombre.isEmpty());
    return nombre;
}

public static String agregarApellidoAlJugador() {
    String apellido;
    do {
        System.out.print("Ingrese el apellido del jugador: ");
        apellido = scan.nextLine();
    } while (apellido.isEmpty());
    return apellido;
}

public static void buscarUnJugador() {
    int idBuscar = 0;
    System.out.println("\n\tVAMOS A BUSCAR A UN JUAGADOR A TRAVES DE SU ID.");
    idBuscar = agregarIdAlJugador();
    for (int i = 0; i < jugadores.size(); i++) {
        if (jugadores.get(i).getId() == idBuscar) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(jugadores.get(i).toString());
        }
    }

}

public static void modificarJuagdor() {
    int idBuscar = 0;
    System.out.println("\n\tVAMOS A MODIFICAR A UN JUAGADOR A TRAVES DE SU ID.");
    idBuscar = agregarIdAlJugador();
    for (int i = 0; i < jugadores.size(); i++) {
        if (jugadores.get(i).getId() == idBuscar) {
            System.out.println("\n\tINGRESE LOS NUEVOS DATOS");
            Jugador obJugador = registroDatosJugador();
            jugadores.get(i).setApellido(obJugador.getApellido());
            jugadores.get(i).setId(idBuscar);
            jugadores.get(i).setNombre(obJugador.getNombre());
            System.out.println("\n\tJUGADOR MODIFICADO CON EXITO");

        }
    }
}

public static void mostrarTodaLaConvocatoria() {
    System.out.println("\n\tJUGADORES CONVOCADOS");
    for (Jugador jugador : jugadores) {
        System.out.println(jugador.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Espero te sirva de algo, cualquier duda me la haces saber.

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma te debería funcionar :

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int contador = 0;
        int opcion = -1;
        
        Jugador[] jugadores = {new Jugador(1,"Alex","APELLIDO",1,2,3,"a")};
        do{      
            System.out.println("1. Agregar un Jugador");
            System.out.println("2. Mostar un Jugador");
            System.out.println("3. Editar un Jugador");
            System.out.println("4. Mostrar toda la convocatoria");
            System.out.println("5. Salir");
            
            System.out.println("Digite una opcion");
            
            opcion = entrada.nextInt();
            
            switch(opcion){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Tu código en caso 1");
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Tu codigo en caso 2");
                    break;
                    
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Digite el id del jugador a modificar");
                    int idSearch = entrada.nextInt();
                    for (int i=0; i<jugadores.length;i++) {
                      if (jugadores[i].id == idSearch) {
                          
                        System.out.println("digite el nombre");
                        jugadores[i].nombre = entrada.next();
                        
                        System.out.println("digite el apellido");
                        jugadores[i].apellido = entrada.next();
                           }else{
                          System.out.println("El id no esta registrado");
                      }
                      
                    }  
                    break;                    
            }                           
        }while(opcion != 4);   
    }
```

Comment: Cualquier duda escribe un comentario

Comment: cuando agrego un jugador y después lo busco por el id me muestra los datos pero el programa finaliza con letras rojas...                         
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at convocar.Convocar.main(Convocar.java:69)

Comment: Dentro de unos minutos lo miro, ahora mismo estoy ocupado! Un saludo

Comment: claro gracias..

Comment: Acabo de actualizarte el código de mejor forma, otra cosa, me puedes decir que tienes en la linea 69 por favor??

Answer (score 1):

Le he estado dando vueltas a tu código, y el uso de estructuras de datos simplificaría el problema. En Java tienes la clase:

- HashMap: Estructura de datos que organiza la información en forma clave/valor.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, podemos modificar un poco el código, aunque le falte controlar algunos casos, como que no haya usuarios con el mismo id, pero esto debería compilar perfectamente, además que puedes añadir más de 5 jugadores:

```
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    HashMap<Integer, Jugador> jugadores = new HashMap<>();
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion;
    while (!salir) {
        System.out.println("1. Agregar un Jugador");
        System.out.println("2. Mostar un Jugador");
        System.out.println("3. Editar un Jugador");
        System.out.println("4. Mostrar toda la convocatoria");
        System.out.println("5. Salir");

        System.out.println("Digite una opcion");

        opcion = entrada.nextInt();

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                Jugador new_jugador = new Jugador();
                System.out.println("Digite el id del jugador:");
                int id = entrada.nextInt();
                new_jugador.setId(id);

                System.out.println("Digite el nombre:");
                new_jugador.setNombre(entrada.next());

                System.out.println("Digite el apellido:");
                new_jugador.setApellido(entrada.next());
                jugadores.put(id, new_jugador);
                break;

            case 2:

                System.out.println("Digite el id del jugador");
                int id_search = entrada.nextInt();
                if (jugadores.containsKey(id_search)){
                    System.out.println(jugadores.get(id_search).getNombre());
                    System.out.println(jugadores.get(id_search).getApellido());
                }else{
                    System.out.println("No se enbcontró jugador");
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Digite el id del jugador a modificar");
                int idSearch = entrada.nextInt();
                if (jugadores.containsKey(idSearch)){
                   Jugador updated_jugador = jugadores.get(idSearch);
                    System.out.println("digite el nombre");
                    jugadores.get(idSearch).setNombre(entrada.nextLine());

                    System.out.println("digite el apellido");
                    jugadores.get(idSearch).setApellido(entrada.nextLine());
                    jugadores.replace(idSearch, updated_jugador);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("El id no esta registrado");
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                salir = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Me sale error en  jugadores.containsKey y en jugadores.replace

Comment: ¿Qué error te sale?

Comment: me sale subrayado con rojo  .containsKey y .replace

Comment: Importaste la clase HashMap?

Comment: si ya la importe pero pasa que cuando le doy a modificar un jugador me sale digitar el nombre y el apellido junto

Comment: A la hora de digitalizar tanto nombre y apellido cuando lo modificas, prueba el método next() en vez de nextLine()